# Run code only once after an application is installed on Android device

Tags: android

I want to run a piece of code once only after the application is installed. After it has been executed, that particular piece of code should not be called again, even for an upgrade.

Comment: Shouldn't that just be a part of the installer?

Comment: @Woot4Moo - What do you mean by installer? I am not familiar with that (on android)

Comment: I don't develop on the platform I just thought Google would have made an extensible framework for installers.  Like installbuilder or installshield.

Comment: @Woot4Moo: Nope, nothing like that exists.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

1. Check if boolean X is True in shared preferences
2. If not:
   a. Run the special code
   b. Save x as true in shared preferences

For example:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
if(!prefs.getBoolean("firstTime", false)) {
    // run your one time code
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("firstTime", true);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: it always skips the if statement for me.. how did you manage to execute it. can you please share it with me... thanks...

Comment: @medampudi - I made a mistake, the condition should be the opposite. see edit.

Comment: This is NOT the right method to do this,because when you clear application data from the application manager then too it will take as a new run even though app didn;t get uninstalled

Comment: @Rauf, You are right, so what would be your solution for this problem?

Comment: @EmilAdz still no solution found which satifies :(

Comment: I think it's acceptable to run the code again if the user cleans the data. If you really think it shouldn't then, you could touch a file on the SD Card instead.

Comment: @Rauf - long time, but still... This answer is meant for usability. e.g. - if you have code that should initialize stuff etc. If you look at it from security perspective, you can't trust pretty much anything on the user device, and then you will need to perform such a check by providing some kind of UUID to your server and performing the check there...

Comment: But before using the shared pref I need to initialize it, Where should I initialize it, so that it only runs once

Answer (score 4):

I've used a shared preference in the past, but if you are wanting to do something onInstall you could also look at a install receiver. MyInstallReciever implements BroadcastReciever

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.MyInstallReciever"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action
            android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: "com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" is not a safe way. because when installing app, application is in STOP status. maybe I could not explain it good but with a little research about "INSTALL_REFERRER" will know this.

Comment: also, it seems that this will only work when installing from Google Play (com.android.vending), not from "any source".

Answer (score 0):

use this simple code

```
   if (getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("is_first_run", true)) {
        /*
         * your code here
         */
        getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("is_first_run", false).commit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a boolean value to check if its first execution of code or not.

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
if(sharedpreferences.getBoolean("is_first_exec",false))
    {
        editor.putBoolean("is_first_exec",false);
        //your code here ...
    }
```

The `getBoolean()` like every other get method of SharedPreference, takes a second default parameter which will return null the first time (as there is nothing in the SharedPreference file). Thus, the code inside the `if(){...}` block will execute only once.

Footnotes: [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences#getBoolean(java.lang.String,%20boolean))

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //  Initialize SharedPreferences
        SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

        //  Create a new boolean and preference and set it to true
        boolean isFirstStart = getPrefs.getBoolean("firstStart", true);

        //  If the activity has never started before...
        if (isFirstStart) {

            //  Launch app intro
            final Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DefaultIntro.class);

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
              @Override public void run() {
                startActivity(i);
              }
            });

            //  Make a new preferences editor
            SharedPreferences.Editor e = getPrefs.edit();

            //  Edit preference to make it false because we don't want this to run again
            e.putBoolean("firstStart", false);

            //  Apply changes
            e.apply();
        }
    }
});

// Start the thread
t.start();
```