# terminating a method in android

Tags: android, methods, terminate

I am building an android application in which I want to run a line of code only one single time, when the application is first installed and run. After that I want to terminate that code until I reinstall my app. Is there any way to do this? If so please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "and run after that i want to terminate " ? you want run only once ot run every time app started ?

Comment: A nice answer by **Binyamin Sharet** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065429/run-code-only-once-in-android

Answer (score 11):

When the method is first run save a boolean `hasMethodRun` in the shared preference. Then you may check this boolean each time the method is run. And when you uninstall the preference file associated with the application is also deleted. So no need to keep a tap on when the app is uninstalled.

Comment: +1 for what i was just about to write :)

Comment: Thanks @Vipul. Some one rightly said "The early bird catches the worm" :).