# How to check if a update code must be performed in a App?

Tags: android

I have the following problem:

I have a App in the Store, `version code 1` now I'm working on a update for this app.
The problem is, that if the user already saved data, I must update the data when the user run the app the first time after updating to `version code 2`.

my question is, how to implement this in android? Is this possible?

the pseudo code should look like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (old_version == 1 && version_now == 2)
    {
        // my update code which will only performed once in a lifetime of the app
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the app version, run your code and store in the SharedPreferences, that you already run your code. Very nice described in these questions:

App version/name: [How to get the build/version number of your Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616095/how-to-get-the-build-version-number-of-your-android-application)

Run only once: [Run code only once after an application is installed on Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065429/run-code-only-once-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) to manage your queries, there is a method called [OnUpgrade](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int%29) that will get called when a user has upgraded his app, and the new version of the app has a version code larger than the previous.

An example use:

```
public static void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion,
  int newVersion) {
    Log.w(TodoTable.class.getName(), "Upgrading database from version "
    + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion
    + ", which will destroy all old data");
    database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TODO);
    onCreate(database);
}
```

Here you can use oldVersion and newVersion to do incremental updates of your database if you don't want to just drop your tables. You have to make sure that you increment the database version number. The database version number is passed as a constructor argument to SQLiteOpenHelper.

An example of incremental upgrades:

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {                     
        if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
            db.beginTransaction();

            boolean success = true;
            for (int i = oldVersion ; i < newVersion ; ++i) {
                int nextVersion = i + 1;
                switch (nextVersion) {
                case 2:
                    success = upgradeToVersion2(db);
                    break;

                    // etc. for later versions.
                case 3:
                    success = upgradeToVersion3(db);
                    break;
                }


                if (!success) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (success) {
                db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            }
            db.endTransaction();
        }

    }
```