# How to create pop-up when first open app in Android?

Tags: android

I write an application, I want to get a phone number, but `getline1number()` not working on any devices.

So, I want to create a pop-up to enter a phone number and submit to save and don't show in next time open app.

Like this:

> [image: Image to show my imagine about this pop-up]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run code only once after an application is installed on Android device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065429/run-code-only-once-after-an-application-is-installed-on-android-device)

Comment: have you tried anything ?

Comment: See the link Mike M. posted, and you can use SharedPreferences to store the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use `SharedPreferences` to do such things:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("FirstTimeFile", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

/**
 * when the app is opened for the first time, no such variable
 * (appIsOpenedForTheFirstTime) exists. So, it becomes true.
 */
boolean appIsOpenedForTheFirstTime = sp.getBoolean("IsAppOpenedForFirstTime",true);


//since it is true, it will be set to false after the execution of following block:
if(appIsOpenedForTheFirstTime) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("IsAppOpenedForFirstTime", false);
    editor.commit();

    //PUT THE CODE FOR YOUR POPUP HERE
}
```

As the `SharedPreferences` values remain in the application data even after you close the app, so the next time you open the app, the value of `appIsOpenedForTheFirstTime` will be false and hence your pop-up code won't be executed.

Ah, as a side-note, if you clear the app data, everything gets cleared - including the SharedPreferences. Read [this official article](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) for in-depth understanding.